# Steam Web API key not working 403 forbidden

Tags: javascript, postman, steam-web-api

I'm trying a GET Request ( GetUserStatsForGame ) in Steam (https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamUserStats)

, But it's not working the output is this:

[image]

Here is my `apiUrl = "https://partner.steam-api.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v2/?key={{apiKey}}&steamid={{steamId}}&appid={{appIdCS2}}"`

I tried it in postman, and I was hoping to get a XML format response.

Answer (score 2):

Within postman double check that your API Key is properly set as a variable. If you hover over the `{{apiKey}}` you can edit it and confirm. You can also hardcode it as I show below. To make sure it is in the xml format add in the `&format=xml` to the end of the url.

```
https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v2/?key=PASTEKEYHERE&steamid=PASTEID&appid=PASTEAPPID&format=xml
```

If you are doing this in javascript, it will probably look something like this, but note that I changed the `{{VARIABLE}}` to `${variable}` in order to dynamically insert the variable values into strings.

```
// Replace these placeholders with your actual values
const apiKey = 'YOUR_ACTUAL_API_KEY';
const steamId = 'YOUR_STEAM_ID';
const appIdCS2 = 'YOUR_APP_ID';

https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v2/?key=${apiKey}&steamid=${steamId}&appid=${appIdCS2}&format=xml
```

I tested these both with my own API key and it seemed to work as expected.